# Отключение и моментальное включение экрана через кнопку power

Tags: android

Добрый день, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886466/overriding-the-power-button-in-android/) написано как реализована похожая проблема как у меня,но почему код не работает, в чем может быть проблема ?

```
public class PlayerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ((intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF))) {

            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "TEST");
            wakeLock.acquire();

            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent inten = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, inten, 0);
            alarmMgr.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 100, pi);
            finishWakeLocker();
        }
    }

    public void finishWakeLocker() {
        if (wakeLock != null)
            wakeLock.release();
    }

}

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PREVENT_POWER_KEY" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Comment: В манифесте прописан intent-фильтр для приемника?

Comment: Выше написал что используется в манифесте

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны зарегистрировать ваш приёмник перед его использованием:

```
PlayerReceiver mReceiver = new PlayerReceiver();
```

в onCreate:

```
IntentFilter screenStateFilter = new IntentFilter();
screenStateFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, screenStateFilter);
```

Причём для событий ACTION_SCREEN_OFF и ACTION_SCREEN_ON это можно сделать только в коде, а не в манифесте: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON

Не забывайте разрегистрировать приёмник в onDestroy:

```
unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

Comment: А подскажите пожалуйста, как именно регистрировать?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hjk4t8 - и возникает такая ошибка

Comment: @ДенисЧеркашин, исправил код перепроверьте

Comment: после компиляции приложение не запускается и ошибка, что приложение остановлено, с чем этом может быть связано ?

Comment: @ДенисЧеркашин смотрите очёт в логах (logcat). Ошибки подсвечиваются красным цветом